# Synchronization Timer not behaving as expected

Tags: jmeter

I posted a question previously about how to delay all the threads in a thread group until the last one had ramped up completely. It was suggested I use a Synchronization Timer and it seemed like the right timer to use. However I have subsequently found that the Synchronization Timer is not only delaying all threads, like I want it to, my test is now only executing the next request after the previous one completely finishes for **all** requests.

My test is set up like this:

Test (20 threads)

- Login (Transaction Controller)
- Do Something (Transaction Controller)

  - Synchro Timer (to wait until all users have logged in)
  - HTTP Request 1
  - HTTP Request 2
  - ...

So for above example:

1. All 20 users ramp up and are logged in
2. Once all users are logged in 20 HTTP Request 1s are executed simultaneously
3. Only after all 20 HTTP Request 1s have received a response then 20 HTTP Request 2s are executed

While I'm after the first lot of 20 HTTP Request 1s to be fired off at the same time, I want the following HTTP Request 2s to be executed progressively as the HTTP Request 1s responses return. I don't want the wait here.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation on timers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers):

> **Note that timers are processed before each sampler in the scope in which they are found;** if there are several timers in the same scope, all the timers will be processed before each sampler.

> Timers are only processed in conjunction with a sampler. A timer which is not in the same scope as a sampler will not be processed at all.

> **To apply a timer to a single sampler, add the timer as a child element of the sampler.** The timer will be applied before the sampler is executed. To apply a timer after a sampler, either add it to the next sampler, or add it as the child of a Flow Control Action Sampler.

Please be informed about [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide/), according to your setup the Synchronizing Timer is applied to **all HTTP Request samplers under the Transaction Controller** while according to your description you need to apply it only to the `HTTP Request 1`

Make the Synchronizing Timer **a child of the HTTP Request 1** and it should resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will test and let you know how it's going.

Comment: Dang Dmitri, is there anything you don't know?! Thanks. Worked perfectly